# Google API and OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use google calendar API with php library and i'm facing issues on the authentification of the user to the google api.

I have a question. I've seen some come where you had to set the Api key / developer key to the Google_Client object with the method setDeveloperKey(), but i've also seen some people who don't. Could someone explain to me what difference does it make ?

The thing i'd like to do is to connect a user who have a google account to my application so he can add, list, remove, etc, events from a calendar. This is what i'm doing for the moment for the authentification :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Test GCAL");
$client->setClientId($clientid);
$client->setClientSecret($clientsecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($callback_url);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");

$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
```

Am i doing it right ?

Does someone have a working commented code that i can analyse ? I can't find one that's working on the internet.. Or maybe a tutorial that explain everything about google api and oauth stuff. I'm so confused about tokens and nobody seems to use refresh tokens, and to me that's essential.. But maybe i'm wrong ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you **NEED** to use `setDeveloperKey` I suspect that its only used for public APIs to enable you to use them but I haven't really tested it or thought about it before.  I will have to look into that a bit more.

This is the code I use for connecting to Google Calendar with Oauth2.  ripped directly from the [Accessing Google Calendar with PHP – Oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/accessing-google-calendar-with-php-oauth2/) tutorial

```
<?php    
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Calendar.php';  
require_once 'CalendarHelper.php';  
session_start(); 
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey("AIzaSyBBH88dIQPjcl5nIG-n1mmuQ12J7HThDBE");  
$client->setClientId('2046123799103-i6cjd1hkjntu5bkdkjj5cdnpcu4iju8p.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('6s4YOx3upyJhtwnetovfK40e');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/google-api-php-client-samples/Calendar/oauth2Pure.php');
$client->setAccessType('offline');   // Gets us our refreshtoken

$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'));


//For loging out.
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
}


// Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

// Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}    
// Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";  

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);    

    $calendarList  = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();;
    print_r($calendarList);
    while(true) {
        foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
            echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary()."<br>\n";
        }
        $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
        if ($pageToken) {
            $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
            $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I'll try that and tell you. (hide your app info though ! you shouldn't show it like that :p) But you don't seem to use refresh tokens, is that normal ? does your redirect uri leads to this page ?

Comment: that app info is changed, but only I know how its changed makes it easer for me when working on the tutorials :)  The redirect URI is set up in the developer console.  I use localhost when working on the tutorials.   The client lib handles all the refresh token stuff.  think you can see it if you print_r the session token

Comment: Ok.. it's working. THANK YOU SO MUCH ! I'll do some change by putting all of this in a class. Actually, it's pretty simple.. I've been on this for days ahahah !

Comment: If you find something interesting while looking for Developer Key stuff, i'll love that you share it with me !

Comment: Get stuck on anything else let me know I take tutorial requests :)