# $_GET request is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an angular project that is trying to connect to google calendars, this way I can submit bookings and they get automatically added the the gmail calendar. This is working but not in the correct scenario. This is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500584/6371663) I have followed to get it working.

I have a angular project that on login will check if the web application has permissions to use the calendar. On return it uses a GET to save the token to the session, however my `$_GET` is undefined when returning with the `redirectUrl`. Even when the param is the in URL. I believe this to be down to angular routing.

At login i check if the `$_SESSION['token']` has been set, if not redirect through javascript. `$authUrl = $this->client->createAuthUrl();` and then a `location.href = $authUrl` to redirect in javascript. this works fine and user accepts permission and redirects back to the next page which is `www.example.co.uk/index/dashboard?code=4%2F5NgsMp8JepEmXVgR8pez0fQdk_jTPonsuExdV8&authuser=0&session_state=2dfb836cfc217135f907c7e6c0d9c526983b6f..9103&prompt=none`

But when I try a `$_GET['code']` this is undefined which means this method cant run which sets the token:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 
         $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
         error_log("tou can access");
         $_SESSION['token'] = $this->client->getAccessToken();
         $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
         header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

     }
```

`print_r($_GET);` fields:

```
Array ()
```

`.htacces` rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php/#/$1
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE**
This the error was because i was loading a separate php from an ajax request which was not being set as the header. once i relocated the `GET` request to be inserted into the file that matched the header, it worked.

Comment: What is `print_r($_GET);`?

Comment: @abracadaver  Array\n(\n)\n,

Comment: Seeing that the page is `dashboard` and not `dashboard.php`, you have some URL rewriting (.htaccess) or other that may be stripping these.

Comment: @abracadaver i have a htaccess. which is `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)       /index.php/#/$1 
</IfModule>`

Comment: Best guess: `#` denotes a fragment and is not sent to the server. It's for use by the client.

Comment: @abracadaver thanks but still no luck. driving me mad

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the query string flag in your rewrite...

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php/$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```